# Azure Function 2.x - Get Current User's Claims

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, claims-based-identity

I have an Azure Function 2.x (Asp.net Core)  and am authenticating with Azure AD. I'm trying to access the logged-in user's Claims after authentication. Previously using Azure Functions 1.x we would get the Claims using **ClaimsPrincipal.Current**, as seen in the code below:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims; 
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory; 

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, out object document, TraceWriter log)
{
    string name = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("name").Value; 

    log.Info($"name is {name}");

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Done");
}
```

Any guidance on how we access Claims in Azure Functions 2.x using .Net Core?

Comment: And what is happening now?

Comment: in .Net Core, ClaimsPrincipal.Current is set to null so it cannot be used to get the user's Identity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature is [now supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#working-with-client-identities) in C# in Azure Functions 2.0. You can now add `ClaimsPrincipal` as a parameter to your `HttpTrigger` function's signature, or you can access it on the `HttpRequest` object via `req.HttpContext.User`.

Support should be coming soon to JavaScript, and eventually all languages should support this feature.

Comment: Thanks Connor. In your link you mention it is possible in Functions V2 to get the ClaimsPrincipal of the current user as a parameter instead - can you tell me what you mean by this, as it may be a way to access claims in the meantime. Cheers

Comment: @desflan, that is the feature that we are currently adding. It is unfortunately not currently available, but expect it in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just post a code example here, see where `ClaimsPrincipal` parameter is:

```
[FunctionName("MyFunctionName")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
            [HttpTrigger(
                AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,
                "get", "post",
                Route = "MyFunctionName")]HttpRequestMessage req, 
            ILogger log, 
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
    // My function code here...
}
```